# Creating a system deployment disk

Tags: windows-7, boot, operating-systems, deployment, partition-recovery

Hi guys i want to create an image of a windows 7 system and use it as a deployment tool and when I want to setup up like more than 10 laptops, then i just connect them on a network and deploy the image to all the computers at the same time.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Your question is in danger of being closed as not being a real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with something like [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) or [FOG](http://www.fogproject.org/), if you want to go with the Linux option.

Comment: Clonezilla is a joke. Use MDT, you'll thank me later.

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft Deployment Toolkit has all the info you need for this -

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/solutionaccelerators/dd407791.aspx

Comment: +1 MDT is a much better solution, it builds images for you, and uses the .wim file format for images which is much more flexible.